# Aggregating multiple columns from data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has a bunch of data that's joined with commas in certain elements of the rows. Something that looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(
c(2012,2012,2012,2013,2013,2013,2014,2014,2014)
,c("a,b,c","d,e,f","a,c,d,c","a,a,a","b","c,a,d","g","a,b,e","g,h,i")
)
 names(df) <- c("year", "type")
```

I want to get it in a form that `dcast` is close to getting it to, with the year,a,b,c,etc being the columns, and the frequency across the data frame being in the cells of the resultant data frame. I tried first to do `colsplit` on `df` and then use `dcast` after, but that seems to only work if I want to aggregate on one of the levels instead of all.

```
 df2 <- data.frame( df$year,  colsplit(df$type, ',' , c('v1','v2','v3','v4','v5')) )
 df3 <- dcast(df2, df.year ~ v1)
```

This result only gives me for the first level of the `colsplit`, instead of all of them. Am I close to a solution or should I be using a different approach entirely?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a single line option with `base R` by splitting the 'type' column with `strsplit`, then set the names of the `list` output as 'year', `stack` it to a single data.frame and get the frequency count using `table`

```
table(stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(df$type), ","), df$year))[2:1])
#        values
#ind    a b c d e f g h i
#  2012 2 1 3 2 1 1 0 0 0
#  2013 4 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
#  2014 1 1 0 0 1 0 2 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close to the solution. You just need one more step. You need to `melt` all values in one column before `dcast`. See the example.

```
require(reshape2)

df <- data.frame(c(2012,2012,2012,2013,2013,2013,2014,2014,2014),
                 c("a,b,c","d,e,f","a,c,d,c","a,a,a","b","c,a,d","g","a,b,e","g,h,i"))
names(df) <- c("year", "type")
df

df2 <- data.frame(df$year, colsplit(df$type, ',', c('v1','v2','v3','v4','v5')))
df2

df3 <- melt(df2, id.vars = "df.year", na.rm = T)
df3

df4 <- dcast(df3[df3$value != "", ], df.year ~ value, fun.aggregate = length)
df4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a data.table approach:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
dcast(df[, .(unlist(strsplit(as.character(type), ",", fixed=TRUE))), by = year], 
 year ~ V1, value.var = "V1", fun.aggregate = length)
#   year a b c d e f g h i
#1: 2012 2 1 3 2 1 1 0 0 0
#2: 2013 4 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
#3: 2014 1 1 0 0 1 0 2 1 1
```

We first split the type column by comma and per year-group to a long-format, then `dcast` to wide with the `length` as aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, something like this could work?

```
# extract unique values and years
    vals <- unique(do.call(c, strsplit(x = as.vector(df$type), "[[:punct:]]")))
    years <- unique(df$year)

# count
    df4 <- data.frame(sapply(vals, (function(vl) {sapply(years, (function(ye){ 
      sum(do.call(c, strsplit(as.vector(df$type[df$year == ye]) , "[[:punct:]]")) == vl)
    }))})))
    df4 <- cbind(years, df4)
    df4
#result
  years a b c d e f g h i
1  2012 2 1 3 2 1 1 0 0 0
2  2013 4 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
3  2014 1 1 0 0 1 0 2 1 1
```